# How to deal with zTree under Spring MVC and sitemesh?

Tags: jquery, sitemesh, ztree

I just would like to integrate all of the above 3 items in one project.
And I have met several kinds of problems:

1. I am not sure how to load the specific js file in the common page (not the decorator). Please refer to the attached code, maybe the js files are not loaded in.
2. I have copied the simple demo source codes into my project and still got nothing. It seems that the function `$(document).ready` does not work.

Here is the jsp file:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page language="java" contentType="text/html"/>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<HEAD>
<TITLE> ZTREE DEMO - Simple Data</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mail/resources/css/demo.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mail/resources/css/zTreeStyle.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mail/resources/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mail/resources/js/jquery.ztree.core-3.5.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var setting = {
        data: {
            simpleData: {
                enable: true
            }
        }
    };

    var zNodes =[
        { id:1, pId:0, name:"pNode 1", open:true},
        { id:11, pId:1, name:"pNode 11"},
        { id:111, pId:11, name:"leaf node 111"},
        { id:112, pId:11, name:"leaf node 112"},
        { id:113, pId:11, name:"leaf node 113"},
        { id:114, pId:11, name:"leaf node 114"},
        { id:12, pId:1, name:"pNode 12"},
        { id:121, pId:12, name:"leaf node 121"},
        { id:122, pId:12, name:"leaf node 122"},
        { id:123, pId:12, name:"leaf node 123"},
        { id:124, pId:12, name:"leaf node 124"},
        { id:13, pId:1, name:"pNode 13 - no child", isParent:true},
        { id:2, pId:0, name:"pNode 2"},
        { id:21, pId:2, name:"pNode 21", open:true},
        { id:211, pId:21, name:"leaf node 211"},
        { id:212, pId:21, name:"leaf node 212"},
        { id:213, pId:21, name:"leaf node 213"},
        { id:214, pId:21, name:"leaf node 214"},
        { id:22, pId:2, name:"pNode 22"},
        { id:221, pId:22, name:"leaf node 221"},
        { id:222, pId:22, name:"leaf node 222"},
        { id:223, pId:22, name:"leaf node 223"},
        { id:224, pId:22, name:"leaf node 224"},
        { id:23, pId:2, name:"pNode 23"},
        { id:231, pId:23, name:"leaf node 231"},
        { id:232, pId:23, name:"leaf node 232"},
        { id:233, pId:23, name:"leaf node 233"},
        { id:234, pId:23, name:"leaf node 234"},
        { id:3, pId:0, name:"pNode 3 - no child", isParent:true}
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("aaaaaaaaa");
        $.fn.zTree.init($("#treeDemo"), setting, zNodes);
    });
    //-->
</SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>

<BODY>
<h1>Simple JSON Data</h1>
<h6>[ File Path: core/simpleData.html ]</h6>
<div class="content_wrap">
<div class="zTreeDemoBackground left">
    <ul id="treeDemo" class="ztree"></ul>
</div>

</div>
</BODY>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

I could not upload the screenshots now as the reputation.
Thank you very much for all your help and wish you a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the reason by myself, it seems that the statement with JSP:ROOT should be the reason. Once I change it to the normal JSP title, it works fine. So to solve this problem, just remove  with common ones, such as `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`